# How to stop Apache from finding a filename from a URL path (without the extension)

Tags: rewrite, apache-2.4, files, url

I have a file `update.php` in my doc root.

But I don't want `/update` in my URL to direct to update.php (because I want `/update` to be associated with a page in my CMS, Drupal 7)

I know that Apache is "processing" `/update` before Drupal gets to see it: I created a new empty folder test.dev on my local dev put a file in it called orange.html and my browser visited test.dev/orange - which displayed orange.html - so it's a case of configuring Apache

My configuration is from puphpet.com Ubuntu12.04 PHP5.5 most settings as default provided

```
 test.conf                                                                                                                                          
 # ************************************
 # Vhost template in module puppetlabs-apache
 # Managed by Puppet
 # ************************************

 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName test.dev

   ## Vhost docroot
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/test.dev"



   ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/test.dev

   <Directory "/var/www/test.dev">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
   </Directory>

   ## Load additional static includes


   ## Logging
   ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/test_error.log"
   ServerSignature Off
   CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/test_access.log" combined




   ## SetEnv/SetEnvIf for environment variables
   SetEnv APP_ENV dev

   ## Custom fragment


 </VirtualHost>
```

How can I configure Apache so that id does not attempt to fetch a file whose name (without extension) matches the URL? I'd be happy to do it for specific cases for `/update` I'd prefer not to turn off the current configuration in case it breaks things elsewhere (regression) like clean-URLs. I'd rather *add* a specific "exception" case for `/update`.

My setup: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Apr  1 2014 08:52:12
```

VM was built with puphpet manifest: https://github.com/therobyouknow/VagrantVMSetups/tree/20140721_puphpet_U1204_php55

Comment: I don't think it's possible. When you type the page name without extension Apache will look for any file with a valid (depending on your configuration) extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is with the MultiViews directive

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews

> If the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo
>   does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all
>   files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all
>   those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings
>   it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

In my conf file for my site, I removed `MultiViews` from below

```
<Directory "/var/www/test.dev/public_html">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And restarted Apache

I found that I got 'page not found' page displayed from Drupal - which is exactly what I want, because it means that Apache has not intercepted the URL. If I didn't have Drupal on the site, and just flat html, I'd have got a 404. (Drupal is not relevant here, it's just my own scenario).

So the solution may be to remove MultiViews but I'd first have to check there aren't any cases where it's needed. What may help make this adjustment more specific (and therefore less risky would be to use `RemoveType` to remove .php files being matched from URLs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_mime.html#removetype )

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a similar looking file or directory instead of generating a 404 file-not-found error when a non-existent URL is used is non-default behaviour.

It may be the result from enabling apache's [mod_speling](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html) but more likely is that you have rewrite rules in a .htaccess file.

By default a Drupal 7 deployment includes [this .htaccess file](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/.htaccess) which does not appear to be doing anything unusual, but it does use the Drupal index.php as the 404 error document, which may in turn do something special in Drupal when an URL matches the file-name without the .html extension.

Comment: Drupal is *not* the factor here - in my question, I mentioned that the behaviour happens with a flat html file in a folder orange.html can be displayed by typing test.dev/orange (on my local setup). I supplied the .conf file for the test.dev folder and also the entire puphpet manifest that was used to build the server with vagrant. The mention of Drupal was really background information explaining why I needed `/update` to "pass thru' apache without it attempting to match it to file, and so allow me to associate the `/update` as a URL alias with a content page. Thanks for your input @HBruijn